# How Do I speed Up Image Loading Using The Assets Library?

Tags: iphone, ios, cocoa-touch, uiimage, alassetslibrary

I am writing an app that is a clone of the UIImagePicker but uses the Assets library. When the user selects a photo, it takes a little bit too long for the image to load. I notice that when I use the photos app which has identical functionality as to what I'm developing, that the image loading is a bit faster. I've heard another responder on this site mention the following in order to mimic the functionality of the photos app:

"Load the thumbnail image first (best with dispatch_async) - that should be really quick. When this has completed, load the fullscreen image like you did above. This is what apple does in the Photo App to provide a smooth user experience."

Does anyone have any code samples of how this can be accomplished? I'm not quite sure that I understand what he means.

Also here is my code for which I'm using to load an image (I'm passing the image as a parameter to another view controller):

```
myImage = [UIImage imageWithCGImage:[[myAsset defaultRepresentation] fullScreenImage]];
```

Comment: Don't you already load the thumbnail of each image for showing in your image-picker clone?

Comment: @huesforalice Yeah I do, but not really sure how that translates it going faster or smoother some how if I do a fullScreen image after that.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The class `ALAsset` has two methods to obtain thumbnails:

```
- (CGImageRef)thumbnail
- (CGImageRef)aspectRatioThumbnail
```

I bet they are faster than obtaining the full screen sized version of the asset.

Also, you can wrap them with an async operation. Be sure to update the UI in main thread. Roughly like this:

```
dispatch_async(dispatch_get_global_queue(DISPATCH_QUEUE_PRIORITY_LOW, 0), ^{
    NSAutoreleasePool *pool = [[NSAutoreleasePool alloc] init];
    /* obtain the image here */
    dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
        /* update screen here */
    });
    [pool drain];
});
```

If you need to obtain thumbnails for videos you should use `AVAssetImageGenerator`. It has a method to obtain them asynchronously.

Look for Apple sample code (AVEditDemo and probably others working with assets library).

Comment: Thanks for that! Had a couple of questions on your solution. 1) If I use aspectRatioThumbnail, then enlarge the image, would the result be the sme as if I used fullscreenimage and shrunk it. IE, does it produce the same quality? 2) Why do you say to load it in a thread, is that so the window transition can occur while it's loading? How would I get the window transition to occur while it's loading, would I somehow use that block as a parameter in the line of code I have above and have it return the image somehow?

Comment: No, you should use the screen size to show it fullscreen, otherwise it will look bad quality, blurry. Regarding the image load, you can have a separate thread loading thumbnails and images in background, then, once it gets the data, update the screen in main thread. It's not easily explained in 3 sentences; search examples in apple samples or in github.